# Ansible - set_facts Set a boolean value based on register.stdout_lines containing a string

Tags: variables, conditional-statements, ansible-2.x

How can I set a variable using set_facts to True or False based on whether the register.stdout_lines contains a specific string.

Ansible version - 2.9

This is my stdout_lines output

```
 {
    "msg": [
        "● confluent-server.service - Apache Kafka - broker",
        "   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/confluent-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)",
        "  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/confluent-server.service.d",
        "           └─override.conf",
        "   Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-01-31 20:57:00 EST; 19h ago",
        "     Docs: http://docs.confluent.io/",
        " Main PID: 6978 (java)",
        "   CGroup: /system.slice/confluent-server.service",
    ]
 }
```

And I want to set a variable server_running to True if the above output contains the string `active (running)` ( which it does in above case - otherwise that should be set to false )

I tried this - but that is not correct

```
- name: success for start
  set_fact:
    start_success: >-
        "{{ confluent_status.stdout_lines | join('') | search(' active (running)') }}"
```

I want `start_success` above to have true or false value

I am not yet familiar with how to process using filters in ansible output, so trying different things found on the net.

Can I define a variable to true or false as output of whether a condition is true or not ? How would I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stdout_lines` is basically a list containing an item for each stdout line. 
If you only need to access the output, you could easily use `stdout` instead.

The following example shows how to determine the value of a variable based on
a condition:

```
- name: success for start
  set_fact:
    start_success: >-
        {% if ' active (running)' in confluent_status.stdout %}True{% else %}False{% endif %}
```

It's also possible to set `stdout_callback = yaml` in `ansible.cfg` for a better formatted output.

Comment: Thanks.  This example was for stdout, because that was the example I could post with reproducible test case.   Would you happen to know, how I can do the same thing if it is a list containing strings and I want to check for existence of a specific string in any of list items ?

Comment: You could join the list items to a single string and then use the same method, for example: `{% if ' active (running)' in confluent_status.stdout_lines|join('') %}True{% else %}False{% endif %}`
`

Comment: Why would you do a Jinja if/else when the condition return `True/False` already? Assign the result of the condition to the variable right away: `start_success: "{{ ' active (running)' in confluent_status.stdout }}"`.

Comment: That’s a valid point for default boolean values (lower case true/false), the conditional statement could be used as a generic template for other values or immediate actions.

Comment: Later I thought I could use the condition to assign value Success or Failure instead of true or false and use that directly in debug prints

Comment: With the above output, I have one other question - let me know, if I should open another question.   The question is - from the above output, if the array contains a string, then get that entire line. e.g.  get the entire line - 
        `"● confluent-server.service - Apache Kafka - broker",`  by searching for the word **confluent- **.  Thanks

Comment: `- set_fact: success: []`
`- set_fact: success: "{{ success + [item] }}"
loop: "{{ confluent_status.stdout_lines }}"
when: "' active (running)' in item"`

This way you could append to the variable every line that contains the matched string.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex_search to check the string you're looking for.
Below I provide an example of a playbook.

```
- name: Check status
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    confluent_status:
      stdout_lines:  [
        "● confluent-server.service - Apache Kafka - broker",
        "   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/confluent-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)",
        "  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/confluent-server.service.d",
        "           └─override.conf",
        "   Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-01-31 20:57:00 EST; 19h ago",
        "     Docs: http://docs.confluent.io/",
        " Main PID: 6978 (java)",
        "   CGroup: /system.slice/confluent-server.service",
      ]

  tasks:
    - name: set_status either to True or False
      set_fact:
        set_status: "{% if (confluent_status.stdout_lines | regex_search('active \\(running\\)')) %}True{% else %}False{% endif %}"
    
    - name: output set_status variable set in the previous task
      debug:
        msg: "{{ set_status  }}"

    - name: just a debug that outputs directly the status so you can use the condition directly to any task if needed. 
      debug:
        msg: "{% if (confluent_status.stdout_lines | regex_search('active \\(running\\)')) %}True{% else %}False{% endif %}"
```

Gives:

```
PLAY [Check status] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [set_status either to True or False] **************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [output set_status variable set in the previous task] *********************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": true
}

TASK [Check if status is True or false] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": true
}
```

Comment: Thanks. When I tried, I get this error ` {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({% if (confluent_status.stdout_lines | regex_search('active \\(running\\)')) %}True{% else %}False{% endif %}): expected string or buffer"}`

Comment: Can you show me the output of stdout_lines. Can you add a debug task to check if you get the stdout_lines output how it is expected and not undefined. Which version of ansible are you using? Mine is 2.13.5 and tested also with 2.10.

Comment: Mine is 2.9.  I also copied your playbook as is where you have the output in the variable  and tried to execute, I got the same error.  It maybe that this doesn't work below 2.10

Comment: I would consider upgrading to a newer version. It seems 2.9 EOL was last year.   https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/release_and_maintenance.html#:~:text=PowerShell%203%20%2D%205.1-,2.9,-GA%3A%2031%20Oct